# Can I go shiny hunting using DexNav before defeating the Elite 4?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've been wanting to shiny hunt for so long now (especially for a Zorua) and just got my last gym badge. I found Zorua in the wild and am currently attempting to shiny hunt them.

I've had pretty high chains yet no shiny. Do I have to have beat the Elite Four and Champion at least once before I can shiny hunt?

Comment: This seems to be more of a question about a specific game rather than the series as a whole. Which game in particular are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

There are no evidence that shiny hunting requires you to beat the Elite Four.

According to [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/2nhyns/how_to_chain_using_dexnav_and_increase_your_odds/):

> These are just some tips from my own experience on how to chain and get yourself a shiny. This is just what I've learned by catching a few shinies myself using this method.
>
> What will help:
>
> - A pokemon with **Sweet Scent** move (to rapidly increase your search level for that pokemon)
> - A high **search level**
> - A large patch of grass (if this is where you'll be doing your chaining)

The only thing that can actually increase the chance of finding a shiny is having the [Shiny Charm](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Charm), which you can get from *Professor Birch* after obtaining all Pokémon in the National Pokédex.